# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException during fetch from JPA repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to setup some data structure for my little project, but I'm facing strange issue. Here what I have:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "INTERVIEWS")
    @Data
    public class Interview implements Serializable {

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "interviewers_interviews", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "interviewer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "interview_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
        private Set<Interviewer> interviewers;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
        @NotEmpty
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "date")
        private Date date;

    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "INTERVIEWERS")
    @Data
    public class Interviewer implements Serializable {

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "interviewers")
        private Set<Interview> interviews;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
        @NotEmpty
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        @NotEmpty
        @Size(max = 128)
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "last_name")
        @NotEmpty
        @Size(max = 128)
        private String lastName;

        @Column(name = "email")
        @Email
        @NotEmpty
        private String email;

        @Column(name = "comment")
        private String comment;

        @Column(name = "technologies")
        private String technologies;

        @Column(name = "location")
        private String location;
    }

@Repository
public interface InterviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Interview, Long> {
    Interview findById(long id);

    Interview findByDate(Date date);

    Set<Interview> findByDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}

@Repository
public interface InterviewerRepository extends JpaRepository<Interviewer, Long>{
    Interviewer findById(long id);

    Interviewer findByFirstName(String firstName);

    Interviewer findByLastName(String lastName);

    List<Interviewer> findAll();

    Interviewer findByLocation(String location);

    Interviewer findByEmail(String email);

    Interviewer deleteById(Long id);
}
```

I'm performing request via mapped method in controller which triggers `List<Interviewer> list = interviewerService.findAll();`I all worked until I added many to many relationship

but when I try to perform request I see next error:

> type Exception report
>
> message Unable to process incoming event '[QUIET] [system.out]
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to process incoming event
>   '[ERROR]
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcher]]
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path []
>   threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to process incoming event '[ERROR]
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to process incoming event '[QUIET]
>   [system.out] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to process
>   incoming event '[ERROR]
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcher]]
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path []
>   threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to process incoming event '[ERROR]
>   [system.err] 22413 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO
>   com.luxoft.hiring.portal.controller.InterviewerController - Get count
>   for interviewer with id: 1 ' (StyledTextOutputEvent)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.ConsoleBackedProgressRenderer.onOutput(ConsoleBackedProgressRenderer.java:50)
>     sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>     org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
>     org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.onOutput(Unknown Source)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.OutputEventRenderer.onOutput(OutputEventRenderer.java:250)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.TextStreamOutputEventListener.onTextEvent(TextStreamOutputEventListener.java:52)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.TextStreamOutputEventListener.onOutput(TextStreamOutputEventListener.java:36)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.PrintStreamLoggingSystem$OutputEventDestination.onOutput(PrintStreamLoggingSystem.java:141)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.PrintStreamLoggingSystem$1.text(PrintStreamLoggingSystem.java:37)
>     org.gradle.util.LineBufferingOutputStream.flush(LineBufferingOutputStream.java:102)
>     org.gradle.util.LineBufferingOutputStream.write(LineBufferingOutputStream.java:84)
>     java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
>     java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
>     java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
>     java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
>     java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
>     java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:823)
>     org.gradle.util.LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.println(LinePerThreadBufferingOutputStream.java:194)
>     java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Throwable.java:748)
>     java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:655)
>     java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:643)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLogger.log(OutputEventListenerBackedLogger.java:135)
>     org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLogger.error(OutputEventListenerBackedLogger.java:439)
>     org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callPlainSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:239)
>     org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
>     java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
>     java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
>     java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:1041)
>     org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:185)
>     org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:151)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) root cause
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

but I don't understand why it's related toArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

in tomcat console no errors, I see only next:

> Hibernate: select interviewe0_.interviewer_id as intervie1_3_0_,
>   interviewe0_.interview_id as intervie2_3_0_, interviewe1_.id as
>   id1_2_1_, intervi ewe1_.comment as comment2_2_1_, interviewe1_.email
>   as email3_2_1_, interviewe1_.first_name as first_na4_2_1_,
>   interviewe1_.last_name as last_nam5_ 2_1_, interviewe1_.location as
>   location6_2_1_, interviewe1_.technologies as technolo7_2_1_ from
>   interviewers_interviews interviewe0_ inner join IN TERVIEWERS
>   interviewe1_ on interviewe0_.interview_id=interviewe1_.id where
>   interviewe0_.interviewer_id=? Hibernate: select
>   interviews0_.interview_id as intervie2_3_0_,
>   interviews0_.interviewer_id as intervie1_3_0_, interview1_.id as
>   id1_4_1_, intervie w1_.date as date2_4_1_ from interviewers_interviews
>   interviews0_ inner join INTERVIEWS interview1_ on
>   interviews0_.interviewer_id=interview1_.id w here
>   interviews0_.interview_id=?

Comment: real cause is stripped and not displayed in this stack trace

Comment: No details on how you perform and process the request.

Comment: I updated details

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue and couldn't make any sense from the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Identity implements IEntity<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Role role;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "identity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Person person;

}


public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    SYSTEM, ADMIN, USER;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Turns out a wrong insert statement in the data.sql was the culprit.

```
INSERT INTO identity (id, email, password, username, role)
VALUES (4, 'anni_mueller@gmail.com',
        '$2y$10$pzgIR0QYo.WyCGnAa9lr4eYC25aO4iFsi/WUzYjwBYDe9iyKZgvf2',
        'anni', 3);
```

The Role enum only has 3 values so the range of possible index values ist form 0 to 2.  But in the SQL I inserted the role with a value of 3. That's the reason I got the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I fetched this entity as JPA tries to map a Role index of 3, which is non-existant.